# Is there any function to create auto-value of Model/Table-Column name in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm setting up new simple ruby on rails blog api with Postgresql which must have 2 parts. First part is creating simple blog for CRUD.It's ready.Second part is triangle checker... I added simple triangle MVC files that has 4 model property > name,edge1,edge2,edge3... Now My program must assign triangle names Scalene / Equilateral / Isosceles automaticaly. For example user entered edge1=edge2=edge3=4 and than name must be 'Equilatera' automaticaly...And i must add edge lengths to URL address... For example: http://localhost:3000/triangles/2/a=3,b=3,c=3,'Equilatera'

Is there any simple solution or method or function or recommends?
All files are here:
https://github.com/SuperSayiyajin/My_Ruby_Codes

Thanks...

- I tried to modify triangle.rb class file but when i create initialize(edge1,edge2,edge3) method,new method from triangle-controller gives me argument error given 1 expected 3...
- I tried to add some if statements blocks to controller and view rb files but i failed.It doesnt work.
- I tried to create Postgresql trigger for db migration but it gives me
  BEGIN is permitted only at toplevel error.

- My Triangle Model

```rb
    class Triangle < ApplicationRecord
      validates :edge1, presence: true
      validates :edge2, presence: true
      validates :edge3, presence: true
    
      def triangle(a, b, c)
        t = Triangle.new(a, b, c)
        return t.type
      end
    
      def initialize(a, b, c)
        @edge1 = a
        @edge2 = b
        @edge3 = c
        @sides = [a,b,c].sort
        ValidLength
      end
    
      def type
        case @sides.uniq.size
        when 1 then :equilateral
        when 2 then :isosceles
        else :scalene
        end
      end
    
      private
      def ValidLength
        if @sides.any? { |x| x <= 0 }
          raise TriangleError, "Sides must be greater than 0"
        end
    
        if @sides[0] + @sides[1] <= @sides[2]
          raise TriangleError, "Not valid triangle lengths"    
        end
      end
    end
```

-My Triangle Model Error
https://imge.to/i/51ydR

- My Postgresql Trigger Code.I created in db/migration and when i run rake db:migrate:up VERSION=my_migration_name.rb >> It gives me it is BEGIN is permitted only at toplevel error.

```sql
    def change
    CREATE TRIGGER triangles_name_insert AFTER INSERT ON triangles
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        if edge1 + edge2 < edge3
          UPDATE triangles SET name = 'Invalid Edges';
        else
          if edge1=edge2 and edge1=edge3
            UPDATE triangles SET name = 'Equilateral' ;
          elsif edge1=edge or edge1=edge3 or edge2=edge3
            UPDATE triangles SET name = 'Isosceles' ;
          else
            UPDATE triangles SET name = 'Scalane' ;
          end
        end
    END;
    
    CREATE TRIGGER account_users_after_update_on_name_row_tr AFTER UPDATE ON account_users
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        if edge1 + edge2 < edge3
          UPDATE triangles SET name = 'Invalid Edges';
        else
          if edge1=edge2 and edge1=edge3
            UPDATE triangles SET name = 'Equilateral' ;
          elsif edge1=edge or edge1=edge3 or edge2=edge3
            UPDATE triangles SET name = 'Isosceles' ;
          else
            UPDATE triangles SET name = 'Scalane' ;
          end
        end
    END;
      end
```

-My Postgresql db:migrate Error
https://imge.to/i/51MXk

-My Triangle controller

```
class TrianglesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_triangle, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /triangles
  # GET /triangles.json
  def index
    @triangles = Triangle.all
  end

  # GET /triangles/1
  # GET /triangles/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /triangles/new
  def new
    @triangle = Triangle.new
  end

  # GET /triangles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /triangles
  # POST /triangles.json
  def create
    @triangle = Triangle.new(triangle_params)
    note=" "
    respond_to do |format|
      if @triangle.save
          if [triangle_params].uniq.size == 1
            note='Triangle was successfully created.And it is equilateral'
          elsif [triangle_params].uniq.size == 2
            note='Triangle was successfully created.And it is isosceles'
          else
            note='Triangle was successfully created.And it is scalene'
          end
        format.html { redirect_to @triangle, notice: note}
        #format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @triangle }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        #format.json { render json: @triangle.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /triangles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /triangles/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @triangle.update(triangle_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @triangle, notice: 'Triangle was successfully updated.' }
        #format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @triangle }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        #format.json { render json: @triangle.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /triangles/1
  # DELETE /triangles/1.json
  def destroy
    @triangle.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to triangles_url, notice: 'Triangle was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_triangle
      #case [:edge1,:edge2,:edge3].uniq.size
      #when 1 then :equilateral
      #when 2 then :isosceles
      #else        :scalene
      @triangle = Triangle.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def triangle_params
      params.require(:triangle).permit(:edge1, :edge2, :edge3)
    end
end
```

- My index.hmtl.erb file

## Triangles

Name
          Edge1
          Edge2
          Edge3
          Properties
        
      
    
      
        
          
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
          
        
      
    
    
    
    
    ```

Comment: Can be done with a `before_save` hook on Triangle.

Comment: Perhaps you should add to your question (using the `edit` link just below the tags), (1) the controller code where you are trying to create your `Triangle`,  (2) your stack trace (from console) with errors, and (3) your full `Triangle` model.

Comment: Those triggers look like they should work. Only you can't simply start writing raw SQL in a ruby file. Must make it a string and pass to `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` (or something like that)

Comment: Given all the work you're doing, it might be simpler to take advantage of Postgres's geometric types and functions. Store your triangles as [polygons](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html#DATATYPE-POLYGON) and use Postgres's built in [geometric functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-geometry.html). Or go further and use [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Sergio and also prefer to go with `before_save` trigger in that case. Not much work should be done, so it is fine to do it in `ruby` instead of transferring this application logic to database.

Anyway, if you want to stick to Postgres triggers, then you can use [reversible migration syntax](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-reversible) or [old up/down one](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-the-up-down-methods):

```rb
class AddTriangleTriggersMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    reversible do |dir|
      # Specify what to do on 'rails db:migrate' (create triggers)
      dir.up do
        execute <<-SQL
          CREATE TRIGGER triangles_name_insert AFTER INSERT ON triangles
          FOR EACH ROW
          BEGIN
              if edge1 + edge2 < edge3
                  UPDATE triangles SET name = 'Invalid Edges';
              else
                  if edge1=edge2 and edge1=edge3
                  UPDATE triangles SET name = 'Equilateral' ;
                  elsif edge1=edge or edge1=edge3 or edge2=edge3
                  UPDATE triangles SET name = 'Isosceles' ;
                  else
                  UPDATE triangles SET name = 'Scalane' ;
                  end
              end
          END;

          CREATE TRIGGER account_users_after_update_on_name_row_tr AFTER UPDATE ON account_users
          FOR EACH ROW
          BEGIN
              if edge1 + edge2 < edge3
                  UPDATE triangles SET name = 'Invalid Edges';
              else
                  if edge1=edge2 and edge1=edge3
                  UPDATE triangles SET name = 'Equilateral' ;
                  elsif edge1=edge or edge1=edge3 or edge2=edge3
                  UPDATE triangles SET name = 'Isosceles' ;
                  else
                  UPDATE triangles SET name = 'Scalane' ;
                  end
              end
          END;
        SQL
      end

      # Specify what to do on 'rails db:rollback' (drop triggers)
      dir.down do
        execute <<-SQL
          DROP TRIGGER triangles_name_insert;
          DROP TRIGGER account_users_after_update_on_name_row_tr;
        SQL
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I didn't check a correctness of your SQL triggers, but if you want to write complex migrations in plain SQL, then you should do it in that way in order they were reversible.

Comment: Thanks very much for all help... Syntax of Ruby on Rails is so different for me and sometimes getting information is so difficult on Google because of wrong keywords.  As you said i will try to use before_save active record call back. I hope i will be success and i will try to understand polygons and geometric functions. Also i try to understand how triggers work.